# Should load balancers ever use TLS session ID to direct traffic?

Tags: ssl, load-balancing

One of my vendors caused an outage today by using TLS SessionID (sent by the browser) as a way to determine which host to direct traffic to.

Since SessionID can leak privacy details, and more browsers seem to be changing the SessionID more quickly, is it fair to say that no-one using HTTPS loadbalancers should use TLS sessionID?

Answer (score 0):

Um - Yes?
SSL sessionid can be used as an optional performance enhancer - i.e. don't re-negotiate keys by hitting roughly the same server each time....
Sometimes we use it if source IP is all from one proxy...
BUT it should never be used for session persistence if the application is depending on it always being correct. You need to use SSL termination + cookies or just good old reliable source ip.